# Selecting which IP address to use for outgoing requests from behind a NAT

Tags: windows, linux, ip-address, routing, source-routing

Our organization has several external IP addresses. I am behind 2 layers of NAT and the servers choose which IP address to route my traffic to.

Can I specify which IP address to use when finally leaving the organizations network. I know that source routing can be done in IPv4 by adding some options in the header. But can I configure my PC to add these options automatically.

I have both a Windows and a Linux Machine.

Comment: Why does it matter which router you exit through? The only practical application for this that I can think of is getting past IP bans on one of the exits...

Comment: i want to see if this is possible. is it part of the design of the Internet. just a learning exercise.

Comment: Do you have access to the NAT devices?  Depending on the configuration there may be no possible way you can manipulate the route solely from a device behind the router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your hardware.  A proper router will allow you to configure which interface, and thus IP address certain traffic should go out own.  Again depending on the hardware, this can mean a virtual interface if the IP addresses you're looking to differentiate between are coming in on the same physical connection.